# How Selenium IDE handle user invoked prompts and alerts?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide, prompt

I am trying to automate testing of search functionality and I am using javascript code to invoke prompts for search term.
Selenium IDE randomly passes through the prompts/alerts or fails the test. I want to to know the specific scenario so i can stop IDE from failing on prompts.

Below is my IDE command.

```
StoreEval | getsterm() | search
```

`getsterm()` is an external function i have in my user-extensions.js

Comment: do you want Selenium IDE to display prompts only for certain criteria? If so, then you can use `gotoIf` function. Please refer http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/selenium-ide-gotoif-gotolabel-and-label.html

Comment: nope, as my questions stated, that selenium ide sometimes fails the test due to my induced prompts and gives me the error of "Acception Thrown:" and sometimes it passes through it successfully, I want to know the exact behavior of selenium in this regard.

Comment: Have you tried setting the test speed to slowest?